# Push and Ssearch linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list which I am required to be used via multiple functions. Where one function would insert data one would print the data and the other to search the data. following is the `strcut` definition and the global definition for the linked list.

```
typedef struct node {
    char *ipVal;
    int ipVersion;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

node_t * head;
```

In the `int main ()` I allocate memory for the linked list and then call the functions to `insert` and `search` as follows,

```
int main()
{
    head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));  

    insert_to_list(); //this will generate data and will pass it to a push function 
    print();
    fetch_to_search(); //this will capture data from another source and parse those data to search linked list function
    return 0;
}
```

The `insert_to_list()` is as follows,

```
void execScanNetowrk(){

    //code to generate values

    push(pIpVal, pIpVarsion);       
}
```

And fowling is the `push()` function,

```
void push(char *pIpVal, int pIpVersion) {
    node_t * current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    /* now we can add a new variable */
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    current->next->ipVal = pIpVal;
    current->next->ipVersion = pIpVersion;
    current->next->next = NULL;
}
```

and execute the `print()` function which contains the code as follows,

```
void print_list() {
    node_t * current = head;
    printf("PRINT LIST\n");
    while (current != NULL) {

        printf("%s - %d\n", current->ipVal, current->ipVersion);

        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

**ISSUE 1 - PUSH/ PRINT**

From here the issue is if I print the data I got it will generate an output similar to the following and I cannot figure our why. The issue here is get a `null` value at the start as follows,

`(null) - 0
192.169.1.2 - 4
192.168.1.1 - 4
...`

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

following `fetch_to_search()` is the search functions where it will parse the search value to the actual linked list search function , `linked_list_search()`

```
void fetch_to_search() {
    //fetch data to search

    linked_list_search(data);
}

void linked_list_search(char *searchIpVal) {

    node_t * current = head;
    printf("SEARCH LIST - %s\n", searchIpVal); // Program prints this line and terminates       

    while (current != NULL) {           
        if(strcmp(current->ipVal, searchIpVal)){
            printf("FOUND %s - %d\n", current->ipVal, current->ipVersion);
        }   
        else{
            printf("NOT\n");    
        }   
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

**ISSUE 2 - SEARCH**

The issue is that when I search the linked again from the above function `linked_list_search` the program outputs `SEARCH LIST - %s` where %s is my search value and the program terminates.

These very confusing issues made me stay late nights and still couldn't get the answer, I followed most of the links in the this Google search (https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=search+linked+list+C&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=search+linked+list+c) but wasn't any help at all.

I would really appreciate your experts help on solving this. Thank you very much :)

Comment: (ISSUE 1) `head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));` The initial node is empty.

Comment: The "problem" of a NULL head pointer causing the insertion logic to dereference a NULL pointer isn't "solved" by inserting a junk-node as `head`. Stop doing that. You can set `head` to the first inserted node a number of ways, at least one of them not even requiring a special-case comparison. I.e. don't use some junk non-actual-data node as "head". it only complicates things and ultimately isn't needed. NULL is a fine value for a head pointer for a list that is empty.

Comment: @WhozCraig, that's more a matter of preference. I'd prefer to use a "dummy" node as head, i.e. a node that does not actually store data. If I store actual data in the header node, I'll have some hard time deleting the node, as I'll lose my whole list if I just disconnect it from the list. So I would have to create an exception when I have to delete the first node, make the second node the new head, and then disconnecting the node from the list. I believe having a "dummy" node as head, though a little waste of memory, is a simpler solution

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you sir for the reply and i will check and post back :)

Comment: @Inox or don't do what you know you shouldn't. The problem you just described is one of not managing the pointers **in** the list ideally, of which `head` is one. " I'll lose my whole list if I just disconnect it from the list". So don't do that. The memory management footprint is of little consequence and ultimately meaningless to the fundamental changes in all interactions with a list that contains *anything* that isn't *actual* data. And it gets even *worse* using a junk-node when the list is *circular*, as you then have *multiple* pointers that could reference junk.

Comment: @Inox Thank you sir for your valuable suggestion.. i will check and post back :)

Comment: @Hasitha, simple answer, start all your iterations with: current=head->next. It should do the trick. If you're using the first node as a placeholder for the list, there is no reason for you to actually check if anything is there

Comment: @WhozCraig, it's easy to say "So don't do that". I can write back to you when you say "you then have multiple pointers that could reference junk". So don't reference to junk. Simple, right? Just don't screw things up.

Comment: @Inox Yes tour suggestion  got rid of issue 1 but I still cannot figure out why the search is not functioning. I think the reference to the list is dropped after printing the  data hence the search fails when i try to search

Comment: Weird, try to print current->ipVal before the loop, just to check if something is there. I don't believe you're losing head reference, as you're not doing anything with it (besides passing its value to a temporary node)

Comment: @Inox sorry sir it was my mistake..you comment that advised to put `current->next` before printing seems to have done the trick to fix both the issues..Do you mind putting it as the answer so that I could mark it?

Comment: @Inox Simple? Yup. It is. I didn't claim "don't do that" is simple, either in saying it or accomplishing it (though in this case it is *trivial*). We can disagree. I prefer my empty lists to actually be *empty*. Ultimately I find it easier to code, easier for someone else to read, and easier to test. Mistakes are loud (NULL pointer dereferences almost always are).  To each their own. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig sir you help and advice is much appreciated sir.. since Inox's solution works and requested him to update that as an answer and I am trying your solution to compare the performance to as my solution requires every bit of performance :)

Comment: @Hasitha there are *many* ways to do this, and developers often find a way that works best for them. If the solution you have *works*, you understand it, and others can read and understand it, *and* it works *well*, go with it. An short example of linked list code that offers by-address management of pointers [can be seen here](https://ideone.com/KdTOia). I strongly advise a thorough understanding of pointers before analyzing it, or *any* pointer-rich environment, of which linked list code almost-always is.

Comment: Good it works. @WhozCraig, now we agree that it's a matter of preference. As most of the issues in programming. In the end of the day, what matter is whether the code compiles or not, if it does what you need, its performance, and the easiness for you to edit or adapt it (and for cooperative work, the easiness to explain to others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a technique that does not store anything on the head node. It has upsides and downsides. I like to use linked lists with this "dummy" header, as it is easier to code a function to delete nodes without risking to lose the reference for the entire list.

That being sad, any algorithm you use must start with head->next, and not head itself, and head itself does not contain data (is just a placeholder for your list).

So wherever you put

```
node_t * current = head;
```

Replace by

```
node_t * current = head->next;
```